# Why does ?A return "A" in ruby

Tags: ruby

I recently came across this code that calculates "4 * n!"

```
def moreThanUsual n
    eval [*1..n, 4] * ?*
    # 4 * Math.gamma(n + 1)
end
```

which made me interested in the `?*`, and upon experimentation I saw:

```
>> ?*
=> "*"
>> ?a
=> "a"
>> ?1
=> "1"
>> ?8
=> "8"
>> ?83
SyntaxError: (irb):32: syntax error, unexpected '?'
    from /usr/local/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
>> ?ab
SyntaxError: (irb):33: syntax error, unexpected '?'
    from /usr/local/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

What is this strange operator that only takes one proceeding characterright against it, and changes it into a string?

Comment: Yep, it's just short-hand for creating a one-character string in Ruby.  Almost no one uses it because it is so obscure.

Comment: It's literally the character that takes one character to the right and changes it into a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question mark prefix produces a single character; the one you write right after it.